# Is it possible to find the Memory Allocated to the Pointer, without searching for the malloc statement

Tags: c, gdb

Suppose I have allocated memory to some pointer in a function `foo`:

```
void foo()
{    
    // ...  
    int *ptr = malloc(20*sizeof(int));  

    bar (ptr);
}
```

From `foo()`, I pass this pointer to `bar()` and let's say from `bar()` to another function.

Now, at some point of time, I want to check: How much memory was allocated to the pointer.

Is there any possible way, without searching for the statement:

```
int *ptr = malloc(20*sizeof(int));
```

to figure out how much memory is allocated to the pointer, using GDB?

Thanks.

Answer (score 30, accepted):

The answer is: it *depends*.

Many systems provide `msize()` [1], `malloc_usable_size()` [2], or similar function. If you are on such a system, `(gdb) print malloc_usable_size(ptr)` is all you need.

**2023 Update:**

`msize()` documentation is dead, but [_msize()](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/c-runtime-library/reference/msize?view=msvc-170) is still available.

[1] http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/z2s077bc(v=vs.80).aspx
[2] http://www.slac.stanford.edu/comp/unix/package/rtems/doc/html/libc/libc.info.malloc.html

Comment: RIP the MSDN link died, as expected. MS always fails you when you need them :(

Comment: @AqilContractor I've updated the answer with a new link.

Comment: It's still blocked for me. It says: "The request is blocked." with a code:
0nhcpZAAAAABKTkLThU0gTJS9NU2vtNgHQ0hHRURHRTE2MTQANWNmZWQzYjYtMDM5Yi00NWZmLTg4ODMtNjQzZDBlYzQ5MTg2
Don't know if this is specific to me.

Answer (score 9):

In general, no. C doesn't provide a way to get the size of an allocated block of memory. You need to keep track of how much memory you allocated yourself.

*BUT*, on some C libraries, there is a function to get the usable size of a block of memory - [malloc_usable_size](http://www.slac.stanford.edu/comp/unix/package/rtems/doc/html/libc/libc.info.malloc.html) (found in `<malloc.h>` on Linux systems, with no manpage). Note that this does not work on all libcs, and may report a value larger than you requested. Please, use it only for debugging.

For completeness, my original answer, which dives into the low-level heap metadata, prior to @Employed Russian pointing out `malloc_usable_size`:

*BUT*, you may be able to extract this manually. Note, however, that this all can vary depending on your OS, CPU architecture, and C library. I will assume you're using eglibc 2.12.1; your results may vary anywhere else.

**WARNING**: Seriously, DO NOT use this except for debugging in gdb. Really. I mean it.

The glibc memory allocator stores chunks of memory like this (out of a doc comment in [malloc/malloc.c](http://google.com/codesearch/p?hl=en#aivgwOHmhBo/mirror/users/j/jeffs/glibc-2.3.2-200304020432-jeffs.tar.bz2%7CQoQ0C8ebp2E/glibc-2.3.2-200304020432/malloc/malloc.c&q=%22Size%20of%20previous%20chunk,%20if%20allocated%22%20libc&l=1685)):

```
    chunk-> +-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+
            |             Size of previous chunk, if allocated            | |
            +-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+
            |             Size of chunk, in bytes                       |M|P|
      mem-> +-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+
            |             User data starts here...                          .
            .                                                               .
            .             (malloc_usable_size() bytes)                      .
            .                                                               |
nextchunk-> +-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+
            |             Size of chunk                                     |
            +-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+
```

Your data is at 'mem' here, and the size of chunk includes the header. The P flag indicates whether the previous-chunk data is valid, and M indicates this is a mmap mapping (for large mallocs). All of that isn't too important; what's important is that the size lives one pointer-sized increment before your memory; you just have to mask out those flags and subtract the header size:

```
Breakpoint 1, main () at test.c:8
8               char *a = malloc(32);
(gdb) n
10              free(a);
(gdb) print (*((unsigned long long*)a - 1) & ~3) - sizeof(unsigned long long)*2
$14 = 32
```

Caveat: The actually allocated size may be larger than you requested. Don't try to get smart and use the excess. Ask for how much you need at the start.

Caveat 2: This only works with glibc. And it only works with certain versions of glibc. and thus may break at any moment without any warning. I can't stress this enough; **DO NOT** use this in your actual code; only for debugging when you have exhausted every other option. Your code needs to keep track of its buffer sizes on its own.

Comment: Or just use malloc_usable_size(), and avoid the painful contortions.

Comment: „In general, no. C doesn't provide a way to get the size of an allocated block of memory. You need to keep track of how much memory you allocated yourself.“ – Doesn't make sense. The question was not on determining the size in a C program but rather using a debugger. Tracking things in the program just to help debugging is not very practical in general although there are exceptions.

Answer (score 4):

**No**. You have to store that information yourself when you `malloc()`.

Comment: +1 -- practically a perfect answer. Succinctly answers what he asked, *and* tells how to deal with the result.

Comment: Thanks @Jerry. I wish someone told me that sooner, but I'll keep that in mind for next few hundred answers.

Comment: @karlphillip "No." - then how did the author of the accepted answer do it? Magic?

Comment: @H2CO3: Don't flag answers for being (partially) incorrect. That's not what flags are for.

Comment: @ThiefMaster I didn't flag it for being incorrect - I flagged it because it does not answer the question. "It's impossible" is really not an answer.

Comment: Yes it is. It is not possible in a way that works everywhere.