# Delete selected location from a set of contiguous memory locations

Tags: dynamic-arrays

I ve the following memory allocation done
int *a;
a=malloc(5*sizeof(int));
Is there a way to just free say the 5th location of this set?

ie can I do free(a+4)??

Currently this gives a segmentation fault error.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No, you cannot do `free(a+4)` etc.

Why?  Because the C standard forbids it.
You must pass the exact pointer returned by `malloc()` to `free()` without any pointer arithmetic.

- http://www.kernel.org/doc/man-pages/online/pages/man3/free.3.html

  > The `free()` function frees the memory space pointed to by *ptr*, which must have
  >      been returned by a previous call to `malloc()`, `calloc()` or `realloc()`.

  - The Linux man pages are not the C standard itself but practically covers equivalent information on the C library functions.

Why the standard forbids it?  It is because some implementations of `malloc()` stores header information at the location `a-4` (or wherever) and `free()` internally reads it by pointer arithmetic.  If it's given a shifted pointer like `a+4`, it will miss the header info and get screwed.
Cf.

- [Where Do malloc() / free() Store Allocated Sizes and Addresses?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/851958/where-do-malloc-free-store-allocated-sizes-and-addresses)

Incidentally some libc implementations provide non-standard functions which return the size of the allocated memory chunk:

- [Is it possible to find the Memory Allocated to the Pointer, without searching for the malloc statement](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5813078/is-it-possible-to-find-the-memory-allocated-to-the-pointer-without-searching-fo)

If you're curious how they're implemented and look into their source code, you often find that they read the header info at `a-4` etc:

- [glibc malloc/malloc.c#l698](http://sourceware.org/git/?p=glibc.git;a=blob;f=malloc/malloc.c;h=d8df9c7762555ac54ecf0cee4d1cbd213cbadae4;hb=HEAD#l698)
- [glibc malloc/malloc.c#l1227](http://sourceware.org/git/?p=glibc.git;a=blob;f=malloc/malloc.c;h=d8df9c7762555ac54ecf0cee4d1cbd213cbadae4;hb=HEAD#l1227)

**OK, back to the original question.**
If you want to *shorten* (or lengthen) the memory chunk you allocated with `malloc()`, you can use `realloc()` as @Gustav said.  But if you want to remove a few bytes from the middle of your memory chunk, you need manual re-allocation and copying.  Actually `realloc()` might internally do a similar work, so be careful with the returned pointer which may be different from the original one.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to free up only part of the space, use realloc().