# Why array size is not changing?

Tags: c, arrays

In this example i want to learn how to dynamically allocate the memory. This is my code:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

int main()
{
   int n = 0;
   char a[]="asd";

   n = sizeof(a)/sizeof(char);
   printf("\n %i \n\n",n);

   char *corner;

   corner = (char *)malloc(sizeof(char)*n);

   strcpy(corner, a);

   printf("\n %s \n\n",corner);

   free(corner);

   char b[]="asdddddddd";

   n = sizeof(b)/sizeof(char);

   corner = (char *)malloc(sizeof(char)*n);

   strcpy(corner, b);

   printf("\n %s \n\n",corner);

   int x = sizeof(corner)/sizeof(corner[0]);

   printf("\n %i \n\n",x);

   return 0;
}
```

The result of this code is :

```
 4 


 asd 


 asdddddddd 


 4
```

So I dont know how to use malloc and free properly. First part of code is clear for me. First i am measuring lenght of array `a`, then i am creating pointer to the same lenght of memory as array `a` uses, next i am copying array a to another place in memory pointed by `*corner`.

After printing string of characters I want to reuse `corner`, so i am freeing the memory and try to define the new lenght  of array because i want to store other (longer or shorter) string. I dont know why, "new" `corner` is printing properly but when i am checking it lenght it shows me 4 again. Why? Is `corner` only 4 chars long? How to recreate corner with proper lenght? I know that this part of code makes no sense but this is only for traning.

Comment: Yes, "sizeof(char)" is 1, by definition, so is just wasted typing. But you have other problems: first of all you need to allocate n+1 bytes to make room for the null byte. Second, sizeof(corner) is just the size of a pointer, probably 4 or 8 bytes--C doesn't know how many bytes are being used there, you need strlen() for that.

Comment: To summarize what is said in the answers, you compare the size of an array of chars (`a`) with the size of a pointer (`corner`) and, by chance, it happens that on your system both of them are `4`. The size of the array you are talking about in the title is also stored in `n`, not in `x`, and it changes (print it to see).

Comment: @LeeDanielCrocker: Why 'n+1'?  In first case i have 3 letters '"asd"' but the 'n = 4', so when i am allocating memory i allocate corner[0] for a, corner[1] for s, corner[2] for d, and corner[3] for /0. Am I right?

Comment: You're right, `sizeof("abc")` is `4`, and that's fine. The standard idiom for allocating space for strings, though, is `malloc(strlen(s)+1)`, because `strlen()` does not count the terminator.

Comment: @LeeDanielCrocker: But why if I reserve for example memory for 5 chars by malloc (for example "apple") I can using same pointer type "i hate eating apples" and is no problem for compiler?

`char b[]="asdddddddd";`
 

   `n = sizeof(b)/sizeof(char);`
 
  `corner = (char *)malloc(sizeof(char)*n);`

 `corner = "adadasdsadadsdaddsddasdasdsaddssdf";`

This code is compiling with no problem. Why?

Comment: The compiler doesn't know what you're going to do at runtime. If you tell it to allocate 4 bytes, then copy 100 bytes to that address, it's quite happy to let you shoot yourself in the foot. C is a low-level language--it requires you to do for yourself what higher-level languages do for you, like memory management.

Comment: Don't cast `malloc` in C.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
int x = sizeof(corner)/sizeof(corner[0]);
```

`sizeof(corner)` gives you `sizeof(pointer)` not `sizeof(array)` as you expect, it looks like `sizeof(pointer) = 4 bytes` in your system.

Please note that your strings should be `\0` terminated and you should allocate memory for the nul character also which you are not doing and it will lead to undefined behavior.

Comment: So how i can measure lenght of this chunk of memory pointed by 'corner' ?

Comment: @susi33 While allocating memory you know the size right? `n` so it has to be the size of the array isn't it ?

Comment: It wasnt so obvious for me because i dont know how to use malloc and i wanted to try this out :) Earlier i was trying to simple "overwrite" my strings but that was disaster :D

Comment: @susi33 ok now you got what went wrong in your code right?

Answer (score 0):

In your code, `corner` is a char pointer and its size is ... the size of a char pointer, whether it points to NULL, a char array of any size, or nowhere in memory ! That's the reason why its size is always 4 on a 32 bits system.

Answer (score 0):

You fetching the size of memory which you just created not the size of array so,There is no way to know the size of a dynamically allocated array , It depends on the architecture of your computer whether it is of 32 bits or 64 bits , 4 bytes is for 32bits system while 8 bytes for a 64bits system.

Answer (score 0):

> First i am measuring lenght of array a, then **i am creating pointer**
>   to the same lenght of memory as array a uses, next i am copying array
>   a to another place in memory pointed by *corner.

In the both cases you are using  `sizeof( corner )`

```
int x = sizeof(corner)/sizeof(corner[0]);
```

where corner has type `char *`

```
char *corner;
```

Thus `sizeof( corner )` is equivalent to `sizeof( char * )` and does not depend on how much memory was allocated pointed to by the pointer.

Pointers do not keep information about whether they point to a single object or the first object of an array of some size.

So shortly answering your question

> Why array size is not changing?

It is the pointer size that is not changing.:)

Answer (score 0):

In C, it's not possible to identify the size of the array pointed to by a `malloc`ed address by having only the return pointer. You need to manually maintain a data structure to handle this type of issue. Otherwise, you would only be able to get the `sizeof` the pointer itself and nothing more.

Answer (score 0):

As someone already wrote here sizeof(corner) is whatever size your memory word is - 8 on 64 bits processors if you compile on 64 bits,4 on your system since very likely you have a linux on 32 bits and than you compiled on 32 bits.
Or you have a 64 bits linux and you do not have 64 bits compilation enabled by default , you compiled for 32 bits.

To compile on 32 or on 64 bits you use the flags -m32 or -m64 for gcc.

As for your question,usually there is not possible to know how much memory a pointer got allocated.

However,on linux there is a function that does that:
[Is it possible to find the Memory Allocated to the Pointer, without searching for the malloc statement](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5813078/is-it-possible-to-find-the-memory-allocated-to-the-pointer-without-searching-fo)

Just do a man malloc_usable_size

However,I do not think the function is guaranteed to work.

I managed to use the function,but lowest dimension that it returns for a pointer is 24 octets.

I have 64 bits linux and the program is compiled on 64 bits.

If I allocate 25 octets,than I get 40 returned.

If I allocate 100 octets than I get 100 returned by the function.